# Targeting dynamic text inside paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some contact information, in which I wish to wrap the telephone number in a `<a>`, with the number in the href, for smartphone support.

The initial markup:

```
<p class="myClass">
    <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">mail@mail.com</a><br />
    Phone: 88 88 88 88<br />
    Fax: 88 88 88 87<br />
</p>
```

Now, the markup will remain the same, however the numbers and addresses will change. Therefore, my first idea was to start an anchor after "Phone", and close it before the second break tag, then get that value and stick it in the href. Sadly, it doesn't work that way, as the tag is closed immediately.

```
$("p.myClass:contains('Phone')").each(function(){
    var org = "Phone: ";
    var rep = "Phone: <a>";

    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(org, rep) );
    $("</a>").insertBefore("p.myClass:contains('Phone') br:nth-child(3)");
});
```

So what I really want to end up with, is to have the phone number wrapped, like so:

`Phone: <a href="tel:{number}">{number}</a>`

,where {number} is a dynamic value, and the rest of the markup remains the same. I'm looking for a solution that actually works, and which preferably cleaner than the mess I made above. :) Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("p.myClass:contains('Phone')").each(function(){
    var elem = jQuery(this);
    var html = elem.html().replace(/(Phone: )([^<]+)/i,"$1 <a href='tel:$2'>$2</a>");   
    elem.html(html); 
});
```

[Running example](http://jsbin.com/osuwez)

Comment: Cheers! Works like a charm. Some day, I vow to learn this dark wizardry known as regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this.

Wrap the telephone # in a `span`.

```
<p class="myClass">
    <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">mail@mail.com</a><br />
    <span id="phone">Phone: 88 88 88 88</span><br />
    Fax: 88 88 88 87<br />
</p>
```

Then do the following

```
var phone = $('#phone').text().split(": ");
$('#phone').html(phone[0] + ': <a href="tel:' + phone[1] + '">' + phone[1] + '</a>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ARUms/

Comment: This solution would work fine, however I don't have control over the markup. I could probably add a span around it with JS, but then it wouldn't be much cleaner than my original approach. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the markup? If so, I'd suggest wrapping the various bits in `<span class='xxx'>` tags, where the class is phone/fax/email. That'll make it a lot easier to target the various bits for replacement. Or, go the whole hog and use the [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) microformat :-)

Comment: Why would you wrap it if you control the markup? Wouldn't you output it the correct way to start. :)

Comment: @epascarello - true :-) Perhaps Nix is only running this jQuery magic if a mobile device is detected client side? Hard to say really, but quite often the simple suggestions like yours are the best :-)

Comment: Or he could be in the boat of tons of developers where the developer is tooooooooo busy to change the back end. Been there many times. lol

Comment: I don't really have control over the markup, no — otherwise your suggestion would of course be the clean and simplest way to do it.